# How can I put a brace after some lines of text without there being a gap afterwards?

Tags: braces

I want to change the following

```
 Jan Pierewiet, Jan Pierewiet,

 Jan Pierewiet staan still  ($\times$2)

 Goeie m\^ore my vrou
```

so that it looks like this:

[image]

I had to edit pictures to create the picture above. I don't want a gap in-between the second and third lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


Jan Pierewiet, Jan Pierewiet,\smash{\raisebox{-.5\baselineskip}{$\Bigg\}\;\times2$}}

 Jan Pierewiet staan still

 Goeie m\^ore my vrou

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can do that with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} %
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

 \begin{blockarray}{@{}l}
 \begin{block}{@{}l\Right{\}}{ $ \times 2 $}}
   Jan Pierewiet, Jan Pierewiet, \\
 Jan Pierewiet staan still \\ \end{block}
    Goeie môre my vrou
 \end{blockarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why the page numbers have been affected in [this](http://pastebin.com/YMkALERW) document?

Comment: No, except it happens when `blockarray` is near a page break. There's no problem if it is nested in an environment, or even in a `\mbox`. Looks like a bug.